# i can't execute my project D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directx-9

i have a problem in my class.cpp this problem in this function

```
D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(
  myDevice,
  myFile.c_str(),
  myWidth,
  myHeight,
  D3DX_DEFAULT,
  0,
  D3DFMT_UNKNOWN,
  D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
  D3DX_DEFAULT,
  D3DX_DEFAULT,
  0,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  &myTexture);
```

when i compile the project Visual studio give me this error:

> 1>test.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu
>   _D3DXCreateTextureFromFileExA@56 référencé dans la fonction "public: int __thiscall Sprite::mySprite(struct IDirect3DDevice9 *,class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >,int,int)"
>   (?mySprite@Sprite@@QAEHPAUIDirect3DDevice9@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HH@Z)
>   1>C:\Users\mypc\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\myfirstsprite\Debug\mysprite.exe : fatal error LNK1120:
>   1 externes non résolus

why ?

Comment: I [read the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172802(v=vs.85).aspx) and it says you need to link `D3dx9.lib`

Answer (score 0):

As ta.speot.is point out, you need to link to the lib files

First, set the library path for DirectX in VS2012 under VC++ Directories
[image]

then link the lib files in Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies
[image]